# IT is possible to use the H option with the environment figure*?

Tags: floats, two-column, double-sided, article, sidewaysfigure

I'm using a two column article and when I use the figure* environment, since it is a big figure it is placed at the end of the document, I would like the image to occupy a full page but not a the bottom the article, and when i use the H option of float package figure* environment does not work anymore? any suggestion ?

Comment: Short answer: no. And you should never use `[H]` anyway.

Comment: We need a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that we can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: just omit the optional argument to allow the default positioning which will be p so a full page as soon as possible, by using the optional argument and not using p you are forcing the figure to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your problem. Here is an MWE for a multipage twocolumn article with a full page figure in the middle.

```
% twocolfigprob.tex SE 548808
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.99\textheight,width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Just use the `figure*` environment.